# How do I keep adding 10% to each output number?

Tags: python, for-loop

This is all I have so far:

```
start = 100
end = x + (.10/x)
i = 0
for number in range(start, end, .10):
    i += 1 
    print(f"{i}. {number}")
```

I want the output to look like for the first 50 numbers:

```
1. 100.0
2. 121.0
3. 133.1
```

Comment: print(f"{i}. {number + number * .1}")

Comment: `end` is 110. Why do you expect `121` to be in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should need to do is multiply by 1.1 on each iteration.

```py
start = 100

for number in range(50):
    print(f"{number+1}. {round(start,2)}")
    start = start * 1.10
```

```
1. 100
2. 110.0
...
49. 9701.72
50. 10671.9
```

Answer (score 0):

`range` only represents sequences of *integers*. You can use `itertools.count` in its place:

```
from itertools import count

start = 100
end = x + (.10/x)
i = 0
for number in count(start, .10):
    if number >= end:
        break
    i += 1 
    print(f"{i}. {number}")
```

`count` is for infinite streams of numbers, so you need an explicit break condition inside the loop to exit.

---

Slightly less efficient, you can add `itertools.takewhile` to terminate the stream early.

```
from itertools import count, takewhile


start = 100
end = x + (.10/x)
i = 0
for number in takewhile(lambda x: x < end, count(start, .10)):
    i += 1 
    print(f"{i}. {number}")
```

---

Unrelated, you can use `enumerate` instead of managing `i` yourself:

```
from itertools import count, takewhile


start = 100
end = x + (.10/x)
for i, number in enumerate(takewhile(lambda x: x < end, count(start, .10))):
    print(f"{i}. {number}")
```

or

```
from itertools import count

start = 100
end = x + (.10/x)
for i, number in enumerate(count(start, .10)):
    if number >= end:
        break
    print(f"{i}. {number}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of these answers seem to be overkill (maybe you need that). But here is a simple option:

```
n = 100 #starting number
p = 0.1 #increment percentage (10% for your case)
for i in range(1, 51):
    print(f'{i}. {round(n,1)}') #print here
    n *= 1+p #add 10% here
```

Output:

```
1. 100
2. 110.0
3. 121.0
4. 133.1
5. 146.4
6. 161.1
7. 177.2
8. 194.9
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using [`generator_expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
start = 100
print(*(f'{x+1}. {round(start*1.1**x, 1)}' for x in range(50)), sep='\n')
```